# code for if and else condition connected with database

Tags: php, database

we are using an extension , so that the extension provides a text box in the admin panel.

if we enter the numbers in the admin panel text field means automatically it will save in the database table

we saved list of numbers in the database .

if the number is present in the database, than we have to display the message if condition

" available", if it is not present means than we have to display else condition "un avaialble"

please give me the php code for these kind of feature

please don't clsoe this question as un clear, if you have any doubts , please comment here, so that i will try to  to clear it.....

Comment: Your question is too vague, could you please explain what is this "number" stored in the database ? Is that related to an object/model you created ? How did you store it in the first place ? Please elaborate

Comment: @DigitalPianism please check updated question

Comment: Thanks for the update, could you tell me if the admin field is a configuration field or if it's related to an entity (product, order, customer..). Please post a screenshot of the field if possible.

Comment: its an configuration field http://prntscr.com/8nzfna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a configuration field, you need to find out what is the path of the field by looking at the system.xml file of the module.

You should find something like this:

```
<sections>
        <yourmodule translate="label" module="yourmodule">
            ...
            <groups>
                <group_tag translate="label">
                     ...   
                     <fields>
                        <your_field translate="label">
                            <label>Label of the field</label>
                            ...
                         </your_field>
                    </fields>                               
                </group_tag>
            </groups>                   
        </yourmodule>
    </sections>
```

Thus, with the example above you can retrieve the value of the field using the following PHP code:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('yourmodule/group_tag/your_field');
```

Edit: according to the system.xml file, here is how you can retrieve the values of your field:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/pincode');
```

However this field is comma separated so if you want an array you can just do:

```
$myArray = explode(',',Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/pincode'));
```

Then if you want to test if a number is in this array:

```
if (in_array($myNumber,$myArray))
{
// Number is present in the array
}
else
{
// Number is not in the array
}
```

Comment: this is the system.xml = http://pastebin.com/WgistWSJ

Comment: Is your field the Available ZIP code field ?

Comment: i guess module : checkdelivery

 label : "Check Delivery"

i did't got the field ?

Comment: See my edit in my answer

Comment: is this correct : http://pastebin.com/cPYLukQk if not please correct it......

Comment: Yes, it is. No need to call getStoreConfig again when setting the $myArray variable you can just do $myArray = explode(',',$myNumber);
Actually my bad, $myNumber is supposed to be the number you want to check. I don't know exactly what is this number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29901/discussion-between-digital-pianism-and-baby-in-magento-2).